# Parsing string that contains user entered free text

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I'm trying to parse strings of the following format in Java:

```
Number-Action-Msg, Number-Action-Msg, Number-Action-Msg, Number-Action-Msg, ...
```

For example

```
"512-WARN-Cannot update the name.,615-PREVENT-The app is currently down, please try again later.,736-PREVENT-Testing,"
```

I would like to get an array with the following entries:

```
512-WARN-Cannot update the name.
615-PREVENT-The app is currently down, please try again later.
736-PREVENT-Testing
```

The problem is that the message is user entered, so I can't rely on just the commas to split up the String.  The actions will always be WARN or PREVENT.  What's the best way to accomplish this parsing?  Thanks!

Comment: @pczeus as told in question.... *I can't rely on just the commas to split up the String* so.... split by comma... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of splitting by comma you can use this lookahead based regex for matching:

```
(\d+-(?:WARN|PREVENT).*?)(?=,\d+-(?:WARN|PREVENT)|,$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jM6vG6/1)

`(?=,\d+-(?:WARN|PREVENT)|,$)` is a positive lookahead to assert there is a comma followed by `digits-(WARN|PREVENT)` or end of line ahead.

Comment: sweeeeeet... far away more elegant than mine ;)

Answer (score 3):

Seems quite simple:

Regular expression:

```
WARN|PREVENT
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/JMS7FlBqsidz9Gbl)

In java:

```
String string = "512-WARN-Cannot update the name.,615-PREVENT-The app is currently down, please try again later.,736-PREVENT-Testing,";
String regex = "WARN|PREVENT";

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(string.split(regex)));
```

Will output:

```
[512-, -Cannot update the name.,615-, -The app is currently down, please try again later.,736-, -Testing,]
```

Of course you may want to adjust regex adding the `-`, for example:

```
String regex = "-WARN-|-PREVENT-";
```